# Mule studio ESB 3.6.0 Community not available?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

According to this link:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime

Mule community ESB server 3.6.0 should be available through this site:

Mule ESB Runtimes for Anypoint Studio - http://studio.mulesoft.org/r3/studio-runtimes

But the only availables are 3.4.0 and 3.5.0.

Is it that they decided to remove it or it is just something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe 3.6.0 CE came out with a security vulnerability that was patched in Mule 3.6.1 CE. This is probably the reason why it is no longer offered on the Studio runtimes update site.

However, I am able to download 3.6.1 CE from this update site URL:  http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes/

Could you try that one instead of the which you're using?

HTH,

Justin

Comment: Thanks, I am able to download it. However, when I add it to Mule Studio I dont see a Mule Server 3.6 available. I can see it only in Anypoint studio. Do you think it is possible to develop in Anypoint Studio but export to Community ESB?

Comment: Definitely. Mule Studio hasn't been updated in a while now, Anypoint Studio is the IDE that MuleSoft is updating now. The difference between Anypoint Studio and Mule Studio is simply the name, you can develop on older versions of Mule in Anypoint Studio as well (such as 3.3.3, 3.4.2, 3.5.0 etc). All of these runtimes can be downloaded from the Update Site I linked you above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin! You have right. I installed the CE 3.6.1. on Anypoint and deployed on the Community ESB and it worked perfectly.